# Vertex-transitivity of the automorphism group of a digraph

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am trying to understand the theorem 3 of [Cycles in graphs and groups](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/bernhard.kroen/Kantor_Cycles.pdf) by Kantor.

> Theorem $3$ If $G$ is a vertex-transitive group of automorphisms of a
>   digraph $\Gamma$ with outdegree $d \ge 1$, then $G$ has exactly $d$
>   orbits on $X \left(\Gamma, G\right)$.

So, $G$ is the automorphism group of $\Gamma$ so it should always be vertex-transitive by definition. Why do we need to mention it explicitly?

Comment: Why do you say the automorphism group is "vertex-transitive by definition"? The definition of "automorphism group" that I am familiar with does not say anything about transitivity. Suppose $\Gamma$ is a digraph with two vertices and one directed edge. The automorphism group of $\Gamma$ contains just one element, how can it be vertex-transitive?

Comment: @bof, you are right. It is not. I assume my argument is only valid for undirected graphs.

Comment: *What* argument is "only valid for undirected graphs"?

Comment: @bof, that, the automorphism group of an undirected graph should always be vertex transitive.

Comment: The automorphism group of an undirected graph with $3$ vertices and $1$ or $2$ edges is not transitive. There is a tree with $7$ vertices whose automorphism group is trivial.

Comment: @bof, understood.